# I added space to a kvm img file but the physical extents do not show up in lvm

Tags: kvm-virtualization, lvm, qemu

I ran `qemu-img resize kick.img +12G` and thought I'd see some free physical extents when running pvdisplay but nope.
When I run `virt-filesystems --long --parts --blkdevs -h -a kick.img`
I see the space was allocated in some sense:

```
Name       Type       MBR  Size  Parent
/dev/sda1  partition  83   500M  /dev/sda
/dev/sda2  partition  8e   8.5G  /dev/sda
/dev/sda   device     -    21G   -
```

So ho can I add that 12G to sda2? Do I need to convert the img to a qcow? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you extend your virtual disk, you need to do couple of changes to be visible.

First, if you have done an online resize, you need to rescan the device:

```
for i in /sys/class/scsi_device/*; do echo 1 > $i/device/rescan ; done
```

Now, you will see your block device with new size.

After that, if you have partitioned your drive, you have to extend partitions. That will sometimes require you to delete existing partition, recreate it with larger boundaries and then reboot VM.

```
fdisk /dev/sda
Command (? for help): d
Partition number (1-4): 2
...
```

If you use LVM, you will need to resize PV *after* your kernel has recognized new size of the partition/block device. This step is pretty easy to do (and is done online):

```
pvresize /dev/sda2
```

Now, you need to resize your LV (also online) :)

```
lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00
```

And final step to be able to use the free space is to resize the filesystem. Depending on the FS, you will either use xfs_grow or resize2fs. This step can also be done online.

```
resize2fs /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00
```

Answer (score 0):

The rescan would probably have helped but to be honest, I cheated. I booted the VM to gparted-live-0.22.0-1-amd64.iso and expanded the partition.

But I also needed to understand xfs_growfs.

I went, `xfs_growfs -d /` and that was it.
(I should have mentioned the file system type in the original post.)